# I want to attach custom ids to links based on query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

**I want to attach custom ids to links based on query string** and I found [**this very helpful post**](http://www.artisnavi.com/ttaching-custom-ids-to-links-based-on-the-query-string/?ref=single) by Gregory (please take a look at it to get some context).

**What I am trying to achieve is**, if I go to www.mydomain.com, i require a default value to be added to the link on the webpage, example: `www.ramdomdomain.com?myID1=default_value`

I guess something must be edited after the `if(hrefvalue==null)` line in the code, but I can't figure out how to do it. Please help me. The following is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getHrefValue(key,url){
  var query=new RegExp("[\\?&]"+(key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]"))+"=([^&#]*)").exec(url);
  return (query==null)?null:query[1];
}
function matchHrefs(){
  var config={
    'myid1':["#topnav a[href^='http://www.domain.com']"],
    'myid2':["#topnav a[href^='http://www.domain.com']"]
  }
  for(var current in config){
    var myvalue=getHrefValue(current,location.search);
    if(myvalue!=null&&myvalue!=""){
      $(config[current].join(',')).each(function(){
        var href=$(this).attr('href');
        var hrefvalue=getHrefValue(current,href);
        if(hrefvalue==null){
          var href_split=href.split('#');
          $(this).attr('href',href_split[0]+(href_split[0].indexOf('?')>-1?'&':'?')+current+'='+myvalue+(typeof(href_split[1])!="undefined"?'#'+href_split[1]:''));
          $(this).addClass('selected selected-'+current);
        }
        if(hrefvalue==""){
          $(this).attr('href',href.replace(current+'=',current+'='+myvalue));
          $(this).addClass('selected selected-'+current);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
$(function(){matchHrefs();});
</script>

<div id="topnav"><a href="http://www.domain.com/" target="_blank">Random domain</a></div>
```

Comment: Post here the relevant code. You can't expect people to go and download your full code. Also explain better what is the problem, your current question is very not clear and vague, sorry.

Comment: question: how would you use `www.otherdomain.com?myID1=default_value` ?? is it attach to `href`? or assign to `document.location` ?? or maybe, on the `action` of a `form`? :))

Comment: Instead of using jquery ( because all the cool kids do ) you should have started with learning javascript. And you seem to be using a year old jquery version.

Comment: @Reigel For example, when I go to www.example.com?r=1234, a particular link on the webpage will have the same query-string.

Comment: @tereško I'm a chartered accountant. I'm writing blog as a hobby. I just want to add a small feature to my blog. Thats all. Can you please link me to the latest version of jquery.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, I've posted the code here itself.

Comment: @ShyamSundar , use the links from [this location](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery). You will need the `jquery.min.js` variant. Additionally it will take advantage of browser cache.

Comment: @Shyam Sundar, you can't edit the content of a page if it's not yours... or you have no script inside a page...  `www.example.com?r=1234` is yours?? I still don't get what you are trying to do... :(

Comment: @Reigel yes, of course its mine lol XD
Visit the following links & mouseover "some link" you'll understand:
1. http://shyam-rss.blogspot.com/p/query-string-testing.html
2. http://shyam-rss.blogspot.com/p/query-string-testing.html?myID1=1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after:

```
<div>        
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var requestid = new String(gup('myid'));
                if (requestid == "") {
                    requestid = "unknown";
                }
                $("a").each(function() {
                    var href = $(this).attr("href");
                    href += "?myId=" + requestid;
                    $(this).attr("href", href);
                })
            })

            //gup taken from here:http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
            function gup(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                if (results == null)
                    return "";
                else
                    return results[1];
            }

        </script>

        <div id="topnav">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Random domain</a>
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Random domain</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it adds the query string to all the links on the page. I want it to change only a particular domain.

The `if (requestid == "") {
                    requestid = "unknown";` is exactly what I wanted. Is there a way to incorporate it in the code I've posted in my question?

Comment: The $("a") selects all the links on your page, you can change that to select exactly what you want using the id, class, position etc of the links you're interested in; it's a std jQuery selector.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to select using the div id (topnav)? I don't know how to write code.

Comment: $("div#topnav a") returns all the links within a div with an id of topnav. Please note there can be more than one div called topnav...